# finding the number of same integers in vector

Tags: c++, vector, modulo

I have a vector of integers . I want to count same integers in vector .I need a simple algorithm for it .but without using too much headers or built in functions,just by a simple algorithm .
thanks so much
example:

```
std::v={1,1,1,2,2,3} 1:3----2:2----3:1
```

Comment: Use map, that'll be very easy and efficient.

Comment: @HiteshVaghani not if memory is limited. Sorting in-place would be easier and more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) them, and then count every change in following digits.

optional: save the count to an output array.

try after sort:

```
int count = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if(v[i-1] == v[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << v[i-1] << count << std::endl;
        count = 0;
    }
}
std::cout << v[v.size()-1] << count << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches, the most common solution runs in O( n log n ) time which requires you to sort the array, then iterate through it to count the longest run, as described by @yd1.

Another approach is to use a hashtable to generate a frequency table. This runs in O(n) time (assuming O(1) hashtable insertion and lookup) but is suboptimal for small input vector lengths because of the overhead of setting up a hashtable and needing to reallocate the hashtable (and collisions, etc).

You don't need to `#include <unordered_map>` to use a hashtable: implementing one yourself is an undergraduate exercise :) But you'll have to do a lot of legwork to get even the bare minimum of necessary functionality.

However, if you can guarantee that the range of values in the vector is within some suitable bounds (e.g. `0 <= i < 256`) then you can use an array as a map:

```
vector<int> values = ...

int table[256] = {0};
for( auto i = values.begin(); i != values.end(); ++i ) {

    assert( 0 <= i && i < 256 );

    table[*i]++;
}
```

Then iterate over `table` to get which values are the same:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i ) {

    if( table[i] > 1 ) cout << i << " appeared " << table[i] << " times." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create additional dictionary from int to int. And insert numbers ( as keys) from vector to dictionary. If number exists then you should increase value of corresponding given key.

Note. This dictionary(map) keeps number of occurrence of integers from you vector

Disadvantage of method (from your point of view) - you should include map header.

Overall complexity of such algorithm is O( N log N). Maybe such algorithm will be faster than usage of sort. You will not use one extra traverse. And you have got structure which has information about numbers' occurrence